# Unable to load rJava.dll - not a valid Win32 application - while installing ReporteRsjars

Tags: java, r, 32bit-64bit, rjava, reporters

I am having problems installing ReporteRsjars package on my 64 bit R, 64 bit Windows 10 machine. The ReporteRsjars package was downloaded from the CRAN archive (tar.gz file) and installed from a local folder.

R is saying that it can't load rJava.dll and seems to be looking for a 32 bit rJava.dll file (error message: not a valid Win32 application). I have no idea why it's doing this.

I have installed the rJava package and calling library(rJava) seems to load the rJava package without any problems.

I've also installed openJDK version 11 (64 bit), a zip file downloaded from http://jdk.java.net/11/. There was no Windows installer, so I just unzipped it into C:\Program Files\Java and added a few system environment variables:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin and 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\server

And created a system environment variable:
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11

Typing java -version on the Windows command prompt confirms my machine has openJDK 11, OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9. and OpenJDK 64 bit server 18.9.

I don't know where I've gone wrong - would be grateful for any tips to get ReporteRsjars installed properly.

```
 install.packages("C:/Users/h/Downloads/ReporteRsjars_0.0.4.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
'\\u\h\Documents'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
* installing *source* package 'ReporteRsjars' ...
** package 'ReporteRsjars' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
No man pages found in package  'ReporteRsjars' 
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'ReporteRsjars':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.1/library/rJava/libs/i386/rJava.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Error: loading failed
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.1/library/ReporteRsjars'
* restoring previous 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.1/library/ReporteRsjars'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/h/Downloads/ReporteRsjars_0.0.4.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: if possible, migrate to officer (that has been written to avoid that kind of issue). You can not use java version >= 9 with ReporteRs.

Comment: Thanks David, this is really useful information. I'm now using java version 8 and both ReporteRsjars and ReporteRs are now installed :-)

P/S: I like the ReporteRs package. The new officer package sounds even better with no Java dependency and hope to migrate in the near future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to install both 32 and 64 bit java version as you are trying to install the package for R 32 and R 64 bit version. Also I think `JAVA_HOME` is not necessary. If installations have been done correctly, you should not need any additional env. variable.

Comment: Thanks, you're right I didn't need to add JAVA_HOME manually when I installed Java version 8. After installing 64 bit Java, ReporteRsjars installed successfully. I did not need to install 32 bit Java as well. So it looks like my problem was because of Java version and possibly incorrect installation of Java.

Answer (score 1):

I run into this issue after installing several JDKs (32 and 64 bit) on my PC for development purposes. Adding this line in the R-Script solved the issue for me:

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:/Program Files/Semeru/jdk-8.0.312.7-openj9/jre")
```

Of course, the path needs to be set according to your Java version.

Settings the environment variable in Windows and restarting RStudio also solved the `rJava.dll` issue.